# Dynamic Or query is empty , gives error - "$and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array"

Tags: mongodb

I want the query to have the or condition where if it is empty, it should return an empty result. But since or query is empty, it returns an error `'$and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array'`.

How can I bypass this, noting if the or query is empty I need the result to be empty.

matchOrs is an array, which is the `$or` query and is usually non empty but sometimes results in an empty array as well which results in the issue- `'$and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array'`

```
const match = {
    '$and': [{
      'status': {
        '$ne': 'rejected',
      },
    },
    {
      'raised_date': {
        '$gt': start,
        '$lte': end,
      },
    },
    {
      '$or': matchOrs,
    },
    {
      'city': city,
    }],
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating the $or object after the declaration of match,
if matchOrs length is greater than 0, then push it to the $and array:

```
const match = {
'$and': [{
  'status': {
    '$ne': 'rejected',
  },
},
{
  'raised_date': {
    '$gt': start,
    '$lte': end,
  },
},
{
  'city': city,
}],


 };
    
  

 if(matchOrs.length > 0){
      match.$and.push({$or:matchOrs});
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine.
But for Better practice you should use bracket notation :

```
if(matchOrs.length > 0){
  match["$and"].push({$or:matchOrs});
  }
```